# Get property for Get-Counter commandlet

Tags: powershell

I was exploring PowerShell to get sample of CPU utilization for couple of servers.
I am using `Get-Counter` command-let for this purpose.
I need value of CPU utilization or in other words cooked value for  counter `"\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time"` for certain sample and interval.
I use commandlet something like

```
$temp_array=Get-Counter  -ComputerName server1  -Counter "\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time" -MaxSamples 2 -SampleInterval 1
$temp_array[0].countersamples|Select-Object -Property CookedValue
```

and output is like

```
CookedValue
-----------
2.90508736147317
```

I just need the value. If I use

```
$array_temp=Get-Counter  -ComputerName pwisdevsql10  -Counter "\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time" -MaxSamples 2 -SampleInterval 1  
[String]$var=$array_temp[0].countersamples|Select-Object -Property CookedValue 
echo $var
```

It gives output

```
@{CookedValue=12.6116279752759}
```

Type Cast to double does not work.
How can I extract the value "12.6116279752759" only.

Answer (score 0):

this should take care of it:

```
[String]$var=$array_temp[0].countersamples|Select-Object -ExpandProperty CookedValue
```

Comment: Thanks,it was expand property that i should look for.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `-ExpandProperty` parameter in `Select-Object`. It returns the content/value of the property, and not an object with the property `CookedValue` like yours do atm. Like this:

```
$temp_array=Get-Counter -Counter "\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time" -MaxSamples 2 -SampleInterval 1
$temp_array[0].CounterSamples |Select-Object -ExpandProperty CookedValue
```

Comment: Thanks,it was expand property that i should look for.